# How to fill certain row with a value from another row in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a similar table with this table below, and I want to fill the "Total Point" rows with the number below it and so also it the NaN and "Terminated".

```
type        boq a           boq b         progress a         progress b
P          Total point       NaN           Terminated            NaN
Total        2                2                 1                  2
Q          Total point       NaN           Terminated            NaN
Total        1                1                 3                  3 
R          Total point       NaN           Terminated            NaN
Total        4                2                 5                  1
S          Total point       NaN           Terminated            NaN
Total        4                5                 2                  1
```

The expected table looks like this:

```
type   boq a     boq b         progress a         progress b
P       2         2                 1                 2 
Q       1         1                 3                 3 
R       4         2                 5                 1
S       4         5                 2                 1
```

How can I make it in python?

Answer (score 1):

Check with `update`

```
df.update(df.where(df.type.eq('Total')).bfill().drop('type',1))
df = df[df.type.ne('Total')]
df
  type boqa  boqb progressa  progressb
0    P    2   2.0         1        2.0
2    Q    1   1.0         3        3.0
4    R    4   2.0         5        1.0
6    S    4   5.0         2        1.0
```

Comment: thanks! what if I have NaN in the replace column?